# CRUD functionality firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i'm new to firebase and having issues understanding how to implement somethings. I have implemented the register and logIn part of the app but am having issues understanding how to update the user details.

Here's the flow of the app:

1. A user can signup with email&&password or via Oauth such as google, github etc.
2. After registering, the user is routed to his profile Page with informations such as name, image, email, password, bio, phone number as seen in the image below(the data there at the moment are dummy text).
   [image: image1]
3. At the onclick of the edit button, the user can then update this profile fields by himself/herself and make subsequent changes.

[image]

So my issues is; Once the user registers with an email and password, the img, bio, phonenum would be empty because they have not been created. How i can implement the app such that the user can add these details and also make subsequent updates?

Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying the code you have is not working correctly or are you asking us to write the code for you.... or something else?

Comment: No ,not write the code for me. I'd appreciate if you cam explain how I can implement it.

Comment: We don't know what Firebase product you're using... and we also don't know where you are storing the users profile data so it's challenging to have a specific answer. If you're using Firestore, then there's some great info in the Getting Started Guide [Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). There's detailed info in the React Guide [Write Data](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#writing-data). The [Users](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user) section contains info about storing user profile data, it may also be stored in the database.

Comment: Thank you ,the doc you shared contains useful details. I appreciate.